# Finding the highest key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just confused about why my code would not work, here's the question and the code I have so far (the test run says my answer is wrong).

Given the dictionary `d`, find the largest key in the dictionary and associate the corresponding value with the variable `val_of_max`. For example, given the dictionary `{5:3, 4:1, 12:2}`,  2 would be associated with `val_of_max`. Assume `d` is not empty.

```
d = {5:3, 4:1, 12:2, 14:9}
val_of_max = max(d.keys())
print val_of_max
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question.  The question includes "largest key in the dictionary and associate the corresponding value"  The title is just "highest key", and omits the "associate the corresponding value" part.  Can you edit your question to make the title match your real question?

Answer (score 12):

your code prints the *key* with the maximum value.  What you want is:

```
d = {5:3, 4:1, 12:2, 14:9}
val_of_max = d[max(d.keys())]
print val_of_max
```

That is, you have to dereference the key to return the value.

Comment: Hmm, so I just misread the question, that's good.  Thanks so much. ^^

Comment: this would be slightly more efficient if you used .iterkeys() rather than .keys()

Comment: @ʞɔıu: it would be more efficient if you get rid of any dict methods altogether.

Comment: Oh, I'm not trying to write the most efficient code (though I would if I were more of an expert in Python).  I'm just trying to fix the guy's code.

Answer (score 6):

this will do:

```
>>> d = {5:3, 4:1, 12:2, 14:9}
>>> d[max(d)]
9
>>> max(d)        # just in case you're looking for this
14
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to find the max key value not the max value.

Comment: in your example maximum key corresponds to maximum value. I do exactly the same thing Nathan does, just in a sane and more efficient way.

Comment: +1, there's absolutely no point in using max(d.keys()) when max(d) works just as well!

Answer (score 1):

Same code but remember to call the value of the key:

```
d = {5:3, 4:1, 12:2, 14:9}
val_of_max = max(d.keys())
print d[val_of_max]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d= {5:3, 4:1, 12:2, 14:9}
```

To print the value associated with the largest key:

```
print max(d.iteritems())[1]
```

To print the key associated with the largest value:

```
import operator
print max(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```