# Finding largest value in a dictionary

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Let's say I have a dictionary that is comprised of integer keys and integer values. I want to find the integer key with the highest corresponding value. Is there any built in method to do something like this or do I need to implement some kind of merge/sort algorithm?

Comment: Already answered on StackOverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1747244/831878)

Comment: Have tried to find an existing answer? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary - the solution is just this: `max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

Comment: max(stats, key=stats.itemgetter(1)) is the most voted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just use `max`

```
>>> x = {1:2, 3:6, 5:4}
>>> max(x, key=lambda i: x[i])
3
```

Or just:

```
>>> max(x, key=x.get)
3
```

Answer (score 5):

There are methods to do that, and preferred way is to use this:

```
import operator

result = max(your_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Note, that for your needs `operator.itemgetter(1)` could be replaced by `lambda x: x[1]`.

Comment: Is there some advantage to using `your_dict.iteritems()` over just `your_dict`?

Comment: @verdesmarald: They give different results (`your_dict.iteritems()` returns something else than `your_dict`), so they are not comparable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for this particular question, where `max(your_dict.iteritems())[0]` gives the same result as just `max(your_dict)`.

Comment: @verdesmarald: You are incorrect - `max(your_dict)` will give you the biggest key, not the key corresponding to the biggest value. To see the difference, take a look at the result of this: `max({1:100,2:20})` (it will give you `2` instead of `1`).