# Selecting only max value in python list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
[{"server":"8.8.8.8", 
  "domains":[{"google.com":[{"time":15, "serial":14}, {"time":78, "serial":14}]},
             {"intuit.com":[{"time":20, "serial":23}, {"time":91, "serial":18}]}
            ]
},
{"server":"8.8.4.4", 
 "domains":[{"google.com":[{"time":19, "serial":45}, {"time":92, "serial":76}]},
            {"intuit.com":[{"time":45, "serial":89}, {"time":93, "serial":74}]}
           ]
},
{"server":"206.67.222.222", 
 "domains":[{"google.com":[{"time":98, "serial":76}, {"time":64, "serial":54}]},
            {"intuit.com":[{"time":43, "serial":21}, {"time":65, "serial":59}]}
           ]
}]
```

How would I go about creating a structure where I select only the dict for each domain with the max serial number and when I have the same serial number, select the max time so that I am left with the following:

```
[{"server":"8.8.8.8", 
  "domains":[{"google.com":{"time":78, "serial":14}},
             {"intuit.com":{"time":20, "serial":23}}
            ]
 },
 {"server":"8.8.4.4", 
  "domains":[{"google.com":{"time":92, "serial":76}},
             {"intuit.com":{"time":45, "serial":89}}
            ]
 },
 {"server":"206.67.222.222", 
  "domains":[{"google.com":{"time":98, "serial":76}},
             {"intuit.com":{"time":65, "serial":59}}
            ]
 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using built-in `max()` function:

```
import json

# l is your initial list of dicts
for item in l:
    for d in item['domains']:
        for k, v in d.items():
            # whether `serial` numbers are unique 
            has_uniq_serial = len(set([i['serial'] for i in v])) > 1
            d[k] = max(v, key=lambda o: o['serial']) if has_uniq_serial else max(v, key=lambda o: o['time'])

# `json.dumps` used for pretty printing of nested dicts
print(json.dumps(l, indent=4))
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "server": "8.8.8.8",
        "domains": [
            {
                "google.com": {
                    "serial": 14,
                    "time": 78
                }
            },
            {
                "intuit.com": {
                    "serial": 23,
                    "time": 20
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "server": "8.8.4.4",
        "domains": [
            {
                "google.com": {
                    "serial": 76,
                    "time": 92
                }
            },
            {
                "intuit.com": {
                    "serial": 89,
                    "time": 45
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "server": "206.67.222.222",
        "domains": [
            {
                "google.com": {
                    "serial": 76,
                    "time": 98
                }
            },
            {
                "intuit.com": {
                    "serial": 59,
                    "time": 65
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (d is your dict):

```
for item in d:
    for i in item["domains"]:
        for k, v in i.items():
            c = sorted([(j["time"], j["serial"]) for j in v], key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
            i[k] = {"time": c[-1][0], "serial": c[-1][1]}

print d
```

Comment: @McGrady..I think you misunderstood my requirement..it should choose the dicts with the max serial number..only if both the dicts have the same serial number should it choose the dict with the max time..not a dict which has max of both time and serial

Comment: @Amistad i update my answer,have a try,I think it's easier way.Just convert dict to tuple and sort it.You will got the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your time-serial list for each domain by your requirement and get the first one, let variable `data` be your input list:

```
def domain_sorter(d):
    def compare(x, y):
        k = y['serial'] - x['serial']
        j = y['time'] - x['time']

        return k if k != 0 else j
    return sorted(d, cmp=compare)

def filter_domain(domain):
    for k, v in domain.items():
        return {
            k: domain_sorter(v)[0]
        }

print [{
    "server": e['server'],
    "domains": [filter_domain(domain) for domain in e['domains']]
} for e in data]
```